# Limit size wget can download

Tags: bash, unix, wget

Is it possible to limit or cap the amount of data `wget` downloads from a site? Either via server setting or `wget` setting?

For example, one page is 1GB size, I want wget to stop downloading at 100MB.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Leveraging the ability for the system to limit processes resource consumption through the `ulimit` command should just work. Assuming you use bash:

```
(ulimit -f 102400; wget $url)
```

Here the size is in 1024 bytes blocks. Note that if you use a different still standard compliant shell, or use `bash` in POSIX mode, the block size is 512 bytes so the command should be:

```
(ulimit -f 204800; wget $url)
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect! (plus other `ulimit` options I never knew about)

Answer (score 5):

See the `-Q` or `--quota` options in `man wget`.

> Specify download quota for automatic retrievals. The value can be specified in bytes (default), kilobytes (with k suffix), or megabytes (with m suffix).
>
> Note that quota will never affect downloading a single file. So if you specify wget -Q10k ftp://wuarchive.wustl.edu/ls-lR.gz, all of the ls-lR.gz will be downloaded. The same goes even when several URLs are specified on the command-line. However, quota is respected when retrieving either recursively, or from an input file. Thus you may safely type wget -Q2m -i sites---download will be aborted when the quota is exceeded.

Unfortunately, as the text explains, this might not be useful for you: if you’re trying to download a specific page or file, this limit won’t apply. The quota will apply only when downloading something recursively.

Another option is to run the download in the background, monitor the filesize and kill `wget` when the file grows bigger than the limit.

Answer (score -2):

Check here for a discussion, the first link in a google search:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16415/can-one-limit-the-max-file-size-to-download-using-wget

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer `Provide context for links
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.`