# consecutive numbered files download with wget bash with option to skip some files during download

Tags: bash, download, wget

There is a homepage where I can download zip files numbered from 1 to 10000. At the moment I'm downloading them with this command:

```
$ wget http://someaddress.com/somefolder/{001..10000}
```

I don't need all of them but there is no logic in the order of the required zip files. I can only see is it needed or not when the download has already started. The unnecessary files sizes are much bigger than the others and that's increasing the downloading time so it would be great if somehow I can skip them. Is there any method in bash to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` which has an option `--max-filesize`, and will not download files bigger than this. However, it depends on your website returning the correct size with a `Content-Length` header. You can check the headers with `wget -S` on a file 
to see if they are provided.  `curl` does not do url patterns, so you will have to write a shell `for` loop for each url.

Alternatively, sticking with wget and assuming you don't have a `Content-Length`, you could force a SIGPIPE
when you receive too much data.
For example,

```
wget http://someaddress.com/somefolder/1234 -O - |
dd bs=1k count=2 >/tmp/1234
```

This gets `wget` to pipe the downlaod into a `dd` command that will copy
through the data to the final file but stop after 2 blocks of 1024 bytes.
If less data is received the file will contain all you want.
If more data is received, the dd will stop, and when wget writes more
to the pipe it will be stopped by a signal.

You need to write a loop to do this for each url.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I looked for the max file size idea and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317945/limit-size-wget-can-download what doyou think can this work? with my original command

Comment: yes, it's a much simpler solution that should work fine.