# How to prevent Wget from downloading large files in a recursive download?

Tags: linux, httpclient, wget

I want to recursively download a website using wget, but avoid downloading any file over 1MB in size. I need a solution which either does not attempt to download large files or stops the download once it reaches this size. I have tried several Wget options so far, but none have been able to achieve this, what else I can do here?

Comment: `wget` itself can't do that. You need a script to probe for filesizes and download files according to your limitation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit size wget can download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317945/limit-size-wget-can-download)